# Cannot dismiss Modal in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, modal-dialog

I have an issue dismissing Modal ViewController in swift. When I call the code below nothing happens:

```
confirmPopup.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have the main ViewController which I use to present the Modal ViewController. This is main ViewController and how I present modal:

```
private var controller: RoomViewController!
private var confirmPopup: ConfirmWaitUser!

init(username: String, controller: RoomViewController, database: DatabaseReference, usersTable: UITableView, loadingUsers: UIActivityIndicatorView){
    self.controller = controller
            ...
    let story = UIStoryboard(name: "OnlineChallenge", bundle: nil)
    
    confirmPopup = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "waitingUser") as! ConfirmWaitUser
    

}
  private func showConfirmDialog(byUser: String, category: String){
    confirmPopup.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    confirmPopup.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve        

    controller.present(confirmPopup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling but before saying anything, have you tried invoking `controller.dismss` instead since it's this one that is presenting?

Comment: `controller.dismss` dismisses the parent ViewController which I don't want to, I only want  to dismiss Modal ViewController `confirmPopup`